# AWS SQS - How do I know time interval it takes from "a message sent to a queue" to "the message being received"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

For example, a message is sent to a queue at `2016-05-19 23:29:05`. And it being received by a consumer at `2016-05-19 23:30:05`. After processed, the message is deleted at `2016-05-19 23:30:08`. That means it takes 60 seconds from message sent to queue to consumer received it, and it takes 63 seconds from the message born to dead.

This metrics is helpful to monitor how fast consumer can consume messages.

To get lifetime of a message, I have to manually add timestamp attribute to each message when it is sent to queue. Consumer will retrieve the timestamp and calculate the time interval.

Does SQS provide similar API to get lifetime of a message (I checked SQS API and with no luck), or is there any other good idea?

Comment: The answer is NO in SQS. The mentioned features are overhead for most MQ server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are attributes on an SQS message which will allow you to measure the time spent by a message in the queue.

Some of the attributes you can use are 
SentTimestamp, CreatedTimestamp, LastModifiedTimestamp etc

I was looking at the javascript SDK, and it seems like some attributes are only returned when explicitly requested for
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property

For the list of all attributes available within an SQS message please refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html